# Do you have any idea about "Not enough storage is available to process this command.", except IRPStackSize

Tags: c#, xml, exception

I currently have exception about XML. I have no idea. So, I post this problem to you guys.

Below is my running environment and problem.

- Environment

  - OS : Win7 32bit
  - Tool : 2010 Visual Studio Express. (Developed by 2010 Visual Studio Ultimate.)
- App. Type : C# 4.0, WinForm.
- Exception

C#, When XML File write down, exception is occurred

> "Not enough storage is available to process this command."

This situation does not occur in every case. Almost all cases have no Exception. But it occasionally occurred.

This Application need to be running always. This problem is critical to me. Do you have some solution or suggestion ?

I already search this key word "Not enough storage is available to process this command.". Someone fixed this problem by using IRPStackSize. But It didn't work in my case.

If you need to know more detail, let me know it.

**Sample code:**

```
public static void Serialize(string fileName, JobItem jobItem)
    {

        lock (AppContext.Current.JobItemLock) 
        {
            JobItem newJobItem = JobItem.CopyJobItem(jobItem); 
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(JobItem));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            if(newJobItem != null) 
                xmlSer.Serialize(fs, newJobItem);
            else
                xmlSer.Serialize(fs, jobItem);

            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code and a brief explanation on what are your trying to do

Comment: I attach own fuction about writing xml for data recovery. I hope it could enough information to understand my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems, that your environment does not provide enough memory (RAM).
Though I would expect to see the word *memory* in the exception, but it says **storage**.

So I would check both.

- Check your free space on your hard drives
- Check your installed memory (RAM). You can easily do this by pressing *[Windows] + [Pause/Break]*.

Since the exception occurs when you try to write a xml-file I'm pretty sure you have not enough memory to process a quite big file.

To test this just run a case where this exception should occur and watch your memory in Task Manager.
If it goes full you will whether need to optimize your program, so it uses less memory, or upgrade your Computer with some extra RAM.

Comment: Computer:
  5.1 Name          : 8SFSE03_IX02
  5.2 Total Memory  : 3489 Mb
  5.3 Free Memory   : 1804 Mb
  5.4 Total Disk    : 118.96 Gb
  5.5 Free Disk     : 87.46 Gb
  5.6 System Up Time: 8 days, 21 hours, 58 minutes, 23 seconds
  5.7 Processor     : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz
  5.8 Display Mode  : 1280 x 1024, 32 bit
  5.9 Display DPI   : 96
  5.10 Video Card   : Intel(R) HD Graphics (driver 9.17.10.2932 - RAM 1552 MB)
  5.11 Printer      : Microsoft XPS Document Writer (driver 6.1.7601.17514)
At this time Computer Information

Comment: I think specific PC Resource is enough to process. CPU 30%, Memory 1.5G(Max 4.), Hard 100G or more is available. So, it doesn't matter about PC Resource.